# Comma separated mobile number Regex validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm trying validation for mobile number(With country code) which is not working. Posting the validation criteria below:

**Valid Numbers**:

- +18790912345 (Valid)
- +18790112345,+18790123409 (Valid)
- +1-2569890912345 (Valid)
- +1-2569890912345,+939890912098 (Valid)
- -19890123909 (Valid)

**Invalid Numbers**:

- +1909890 (Invalid)
- 9800112345 (Invalid - without country code)
- +1 9092345690 (Invalid-Containing spaces in between)

I've tried with the below regex code's but it's not passing the criteria.

```
/^[+-][1-9]{0,1}[0-9-]{0,16}[,]$/
```

and

```
^[+-][0-9-]{0,16}+(,[+-][0-9-]{0,16}+)*$
```

**What number is considered valid**

A valid phone number is any number starting with either `+` or `-` and containing from 8 to 16 digits that can be optionally separated with any number of hyphens. It cannot contains whitespaces.

Comment: You should not use possessive quantifiers in JS regexps, replace all `{0,16}+` with `{0,16}`. However, this won't fix the whole pattern, that [second regex](https://regex101.com/r/vs74kt/1) will match `+1909890`. Why is `+1909890` invalid?

Comment: Why is only 1 a valid contry code?

Comment: Why is `-19890123909` valid?

Comment: @mplungjan -19890123909. Yes it's valid.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - +1909890 is invalid because of the length. Min length should be 8 and max would be 13

Comment: Are you sure? 8 to 13 won't match `+1-2569890912345` and `+1-2569890912345,+939890912098` then. Did you mean 8 to 16?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew -Sorry typo. Yes it was 8 to 16

Comment: Try `^[+-]\d(?:-*\d){7,15}(?:,[+-]\d(?:-*\d){7,15})*$`, see https://regex101.com/r/vs74kt/2

Comment: Is it any good? Or do you also expect to match `+` / `-` at the end of the strings? Your question is so unclear, please put all the requirements into the question body.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Yeah so good. Will update the question as well. Pls post this answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you want to match numbers that contain 8 to 16 *digits* with optional hyphens in between the digits.

In this case, you can use

```
^[+-]\d(?:-*\d){7,15}(?:,[+-]\d(?:-*\d){7,15})*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vs74kt/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[+-]` - a `+` or `-`
- `\d(?:-*\d){7,15}` - a digit, then seven to fifteen repetitions of zero or more hyphens and a digit (so, 8 to 16 digits all in all)
- `(?:` - start of a grouping:

  - `,`  - a comma
  - `[+-]` - `+` or `-`
  - `\d(?:-*\d){7,15}` - see above (a phone number pattern part)
- `)*` - end of the grouping, zero or more repetitions
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score -1):

```
^\+(?:\d{1,4}-)?\d{1,14}(?:,\+(?:\d{1,4}-)?\d{1,14})*$
```

Comment: Please explain how this RegEx solves the issue

Answer (score -2):

Updated Regex: `^([+-][1-9][0-9]{0,2}\S[0-9-\S]{5,14}|[+-]\d{6,14})$`

Comment: Tried this, failing on this criteria +1-2569890912345,+939890912098

Comment: Please explain how this RegEx solves the issue